# SautinSoft HTML-to-RTF and UNC Paths

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, rtf, unc

Has anybody successfully used the SautinSoft HTML to RTF DLL which has images with a UNC path?

When we use the component to transform a HTML document with images whose src attribute is pointing to a UNC path the resulting RTF document has the images missing.

When navigating to the HTML page directly - with UNC paths as the  source - the images are displaying correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no longer relevant as we've moved onto using [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx) as the tool to export the HTML to RTF format - from first impressions it appears (a) a lot more flexible, (b) easier to read, and (c) has proper documentation.

Answer (score 0):

My name is Max from SautinSoft, the current version of the HTML to RTF .Net component supports UNC paths. Thanks for noticing about this issue!

Comment: Do you have any suggestion on this related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50969797/sautinsoft-pdffocus-exception-after-migration-to-net-core-2-1/51036842#comment97084273_51036842) of your `RTF to HTML.Net` C# assembly?

Answer (score 0):

Try wkhtmltopdf

http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/