# Sautinsoft PdfFocus exception after migration to .NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a purchased license of the DLLs (6.9.4.10) and my `*.csproj` contains this:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.1.0"/>
  ...
  <PackageReference Include="System.IO.Packaging" Version="4.5.0"/>
  <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Encoding.CodePages" Version="4.5.0"/>
  <PackageReference Include="ZKWeb.System.Drawing" Version="4.0.0"/>
</ItemGroup>
...
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="SautinSoft.PdfFocus">
    <HintPath>..\PDF Focus .Net Full (6.9.4.10)\DLLs\Net Core 2.0\SautinSoft.PdfFocus.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

I am trying to convert a PDF into a DOCX-file (which worked in .NET 4.5).

This is the relevant part of the code:

```
....
SautinSoft.PdfFocus f = new SautinSoft.PdfFocus();
f.Serial = Settings.GetAppSetting("PdfFocusSerial", "**MySerial**");
f.OpenPdf(buffer);

if (f.PageCount > 0)
{
    f.WordOptions.Format = SautinSoft.PdfFocus.CWordOptions.eWordDocument.Docx;

    var result = f.ToWord(); //f.Exception set after this
    ...
}
...
```

I've checked that the same `buffer` is sent in as in the old code, but the output differs by some bytes. And I get an Exception set in `f.Exception`, which is:

```
{System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException:
The given key '0' was not present in the dictionary. ...
```

When I try to open the newly created `*.docx`-file, Word says it's damaged. After clicking through some dialogs it can still open the file.

Anyone have any ideas?

Is this a known bug for this library in .Net Core 2.1? (Only 2.0 is mentioned on their website)

I've also tried the free version published on NuGet with the same results.

**EDIT**

This was indeed a bug in the .NET Core specific version. They have fixed this in version `6.9.6.29`.

Comment: Try vendor [support](https://sautinsoft.com/support.php) if you haven't already.

Comment: @MarkG Yes I did, they said they would try and answer quickly. No response yet. Any comment in the downvote please so I can try to improve my question?

Comment: I didn't downvote your question, but have you tried using this library in .NET Core 2.0 instead?  BTW, you should be using Microsoft.AspNetCore.App instead of Microsoft.AspNetCore.All when using .NET Core 2.1 in your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Name is Dmitry and I work in SautinSoft.
Thank you for your issue. You are right. We have some problems with PDF Focus.Net and Net Core 2.1
Our developers try to fix this issue. We have found where is a bug (resources/fonts) and I hope, that we will prepare a new version very quickly. 
I'll inform you.

Comment: We've fixed this issue. Now the PDF Focus .Net supports .Net Core 2.0 - 100%

Comment: this is still not fixed. We get a NullReferenceException from the Exception property.

Comment: @DmitryFeoktistov Does your `RTF to HTML.NET` assembly work on `UWP` projects? After installing your NuGet package from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sautinsoft.rtftohtml/), on a UWP project on `VS2017`, I get the following error on very first line of the code: `SautinSoft.RtfToHtml r = new SautinSoft.RtfToHtml();` **Error**: `Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing.Common, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.`. I did reference `using SautinSoft;

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use "RTF to HTML" for Net Core 2.X-6.X please add these references in your project:

```
System.Drawing.Common, 4.7.0 or up.
System.IO.Packaging, 4.4.0 or up.
System.Text.Encoding.CodePages, 4.5.0 or up.
System.Xml.XPath.XmlDocument, 4.3.0 or up.
```

But If it will be Net Core 7.X for LinuxOS - it doesn't work, because the System.Drawing.Common NuGet package is now attributed as a Windows-specific library. The platform analyzer emits warning at compile time when compiling for non-Windows operating systems.